# Spring Work Function if compressed by two equal forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

If I have a spring of length $d$, constant $k$ and I apply equal forces to compress the spring, what would the work be done on the spring if the compression is $\Delta d$?

I'm not sure how I would calculate using Hooke's law. Would I calculate using one work functions? or would I calculate summing two work functions where the bounds would be $\Delta d/2$?

Answer (score 1):

If you fix one end of the spring to a wall and compress it from the other end, you are essentially applying equal forces to each end of the spring.  The scenario you propose is no different than a fixed end spring, except that the spring center of mass will end up in a different final position in the fixed end case.  The work done will be the same.